# How big can be the Plone 4 database?

Tags: plone, scalability

In 2004 Mahendra gives a talk about using Plone with DSpace to manage digital assets.

http://linux-bangalore.org/2004/schedules/talkdetails.php?talkcode=C0300032

Mahendra said:

> Zope provides a lot of features and an excellent architecture for handling digital content. However, Zope has issues as the stored data scales to the order of Giga/Tera bytes. A combination of Zope + Plone is great as a portal management system, but if an attempt is made to use it for storing digital assets, performance can drop down.

So he propposes using DSpace to manage digital assets instead that Plone. But maybe it has changed today. What are the limits to use Plone as a Digital Assets Manager now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since that article was written, the ZODB (Zope's data storage system) has grown support for blobs stored as separate files on the filesystem, which basically means you're limited by the capabilities of the filesystem in use. I know of multiple installations with more than 20GB of data, which was the number mentioned in the article.

Now if you want to catalog the assets so they can be easily found, then you'll hit other limits based on the sophistication of your catalog algorithms and data structures. Plone can handle quite a bit of data, but it tends to require lots of RAM and careful tuning (and probably customization) once you get beyond 50,000 content items or so.

Comment: I know and have worked with Plone installations containing both upwards of one million documents and over 100GB. Though those tend to be quite heavily customized sites with a dedicated cluster of machines to run it. The practical limit is usually on the active working set of data, and not so much on a potential long tail archive of rarely to never accessed data.